# Server receiving data after connection has been made

Tags: client, client-server, communication, remote-access

A server is listening, let's say, on port 3000. When he receives a connection request and the connection is successful, if i call a function, let's say "getRemotePort" it will say 1234. My question is, the server will send data to the remote devise (client) on port 1234, but what about the other way around? Will the client keep sending data on the same port, in this case 3000? So everything that the server will receive (connection requests and other data) will come through the same port?

Comment: Are you talking about a concrete protocol/application/etc.? Because right now I think all we could say is "It depends on how you program it".

Comment: I've implemented a server in Java to which multiple Android devices are connected, and i don't really know how the connections work. Does the server handle multiple connections on port 3000 (both connection requests and other data) or what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it will
2. This is not a problem.

The point behind this is, that a connection is defined by the (LocalIP, LocalPort, RemoteIP, RemotePort) tupel - this is the only combination, that has to be unique.

On the performance side, this is no problem as well: A port is a logic construct, that has no limiting effect on the throughput of a connection, some edge cases aside (Very high latency combined with very high throughput can create a case, where a single connection can not saturate a physical link, so a second connection, requiring a second port, can speed things up. Mind though, that even in this case not the port count, but the connection count is to blame - they just happen to be 1:1)

Comment: So if i were to close all ports on the server, and leave only the 3000 for example, the server can handle all connections through that port?...it won't need more